# Oracle Apex : How to access check box checked values from PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a checkbox item P50_SELECT. How do i get the list of checked values of P50_SELECT inside a PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below, and var will contain the checked values.  The item itself stores the values, not all of the options. This will not be a list it will be a comma or colon delimited string.

```
declare
var varchar2(500);

begin

var := :P50_SELECT ;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL you access them via `:P50_SELECT` ( or `v('P50_SELECT')` ). It will be a colon delimited list containing only the value of the checked items. You can iterate over it by first converting it to an array using `apex_util.string_to_table(:P50_SELECT)`